# How to fix case sensitivity in Windows Git repository

Tags: git, redmine

We are developing on exclusively Windows machines and host MSysGit on a Werver 2008 machine. We use Redmine (BitNami Redmine Stack) as our issue tracking/project management system.

While we have no problem at all with Git and the development machines, we DO have an issue with how the Repository displays in Redmine, due to what looks like case sensetivity issues.

The Redmine Repository is displaying "duplicate" (well not duplicate exactly) trees as below, presumably due to some files being commited with lower case paths (for some reason unknown to me)

```
+-Develop
|  |
|  +-Library .....
|  |
|  +-AutomatedTests .....
|
+-develop
   |
   +-library .....
```

While this isn't life threatening as clones, and checkouts to Windows don't have this issue, it is rather annoying for browsing code in Redmine.

Is there a (easy considering it's a very large repository) way to either
a) make redmine case insensetive while displaying the tree.
or
b) fix the issue with the lower case paths (we standardise on Camel case)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding `ignorecase = true` in `.git/config`?

Comment: that is already set true, i think it may be down to Redmine displaying that way, I know it pulls git changesets and populates MySql tables based on them. So maybe it's down to Redmine/MySql seeing the paths as different, where Windows wont, so my question is really is do i do something to Redmine, or do i start renaming the files in GIT ?

Comment: ignorecase in git config is for case comparisons when diffing files

Comment: @RobertChrist Actually, the `ignorecase` does make git able to see filename case changes. I just confirmed this a few minutes ago. However, it's not sufficient to solve the problem, if you're doing renames in Windows explorer. (as it only makes it see the new file, thus leading to two versions in the repo, instead of recognizing it as a simple rename/case-change)

Answer (score 0):

Redmine will see those as different places. Even though you have ignore case on, always tab-complete when going into directories and specifying files. Use `git filter-branch` to fix the casing. This will change where all references point but it may be a good thing to do at this point.

Comment: we use tortoise git client & smartGit clients and only resort to the command line when neccessary, and never used git tab-completion so not sure how that's of any benefit.

Comment: The benefit would be that you would have consistent naming and not have the duplication if you tab completed.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant enforce that on our dev team. Also we need to retain all file history and not require a --follow in the log to follow history through renames (well this is all in the ideal world, else I may look at patching the redmine display)